# UnicodeEncodeError when MySQLdb show warnings

Tags: python, mysql, exception, mysql-python

What I use:  Python2.7 / MySQLdb 1.2.3

when I user MySQLdb.cursors to execute `INSERT IGNORE INTO reporter('张三', '2013-11-11'), ('张三', '2013-11-11')`,
it thow a UnicodeEncodeError Error like this, it happens when show warnings

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 224, in executemany
    if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 92, in _warning_check
    warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/warnings.py", line 29, in _show_warning
    file.write(formatwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/warnings.py", line 38, in formatwarning
    s =  "%s:%s: %s: %s\n" % (filename, lineno, category.__name__, message)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 17-18: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**What should I do?**

This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import MySQLdb

db_conn = MySQLdb.connect(
    host='localhost', user='root', passwd='', charset='utf8', db='test')
cursor = db_conn.cursor()
cursor.executemany(
    'INSERT IGNORE INTO unicode_test values(%s, %s)',
    [('张三', '2013-11-11'), ('张三', '2013-11-11')])
db_conn.commit()
cursor.close()
db_conn.close()
```

it comes

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cooper/Document/20131106.py", line 9, in <module>
    [('张三', '2013-11-11'), ('张三', '2013-11-11')])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 224, in executemany
    if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 92, in _warning_check
    warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/warnings.py", line 29, in _show_warning
    file.write(formatwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/warnings.py", line 38, in formatwarning
    s =  "%s:%s: %s: %s\n" % (filename, lineno, category.__name__, message)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 17-18: ordinal not in range(128)
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

This is the table I use in MariaDB 10.0

```
CREATE TABLE `unicode_test` (
 `name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `date_of` date NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`name`,`date_of`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: You have to encoding special word to utf8. `u'张三'.encode('utf8')`

Comment: thanks but it result the same error, the code comes `cursor.executemany('INSERT IGNORE INTO unicode_test values(%s, %s)', [(u'张三'.encode('utf-8'), '2013-11-11'), (u'张三'.encode('utf-8'), '2013-11-11')])`

Comment: did you resolve the issue?

Comment: sorry for late, I havn't 'resolve' it, so I have no choice but ignore it, but warnings should be print in some way.
What you mean making warnings toleraent to non-ascii encoding? could you show some code?

Comment: @GCooper, plase preceed message with `@alko` tag, that way I receive it in my inbox and won't miss. By making tolerant I mean monkey-patching either warnings, or MySQLdb. I'll come with sample code if you insist, but I'd suggest first to find out what those warnings are via mysql console.

Comment: @alko get it, thanks. I'll set `Cursor._defer_warnings = True` and so we can call `db_conn.show_warnings()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, seems that I have a clue. It seems that we just missed key point in your trace, that unicode error is raised in warning, not in MySQL.

To get rid of this, you can filter MySQLdb warnings out adding

```
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=MySQLdb.Warning)
```

to your script. Do not know what warnings are those exactly, on my installation there are none. You can check it manually executing your query in mysql console and running `SHOW WARNINGS;` afterwards.

Alternatively, you can patch relevant function from `warnings.py`, making it tolerant to non-ascii encodings, to check it out with python.

Comment: I wish there was a better answer than simply disabling all the warnings or hacking your installation of Python.  Can the `warnings` module be configured encode its output as UTF-8 instead of ASCII?  Or to respect `PYTHONIOENCODING`?  (I am asking because I don't know.)

Answer (score 0):

Show your table/MySQL parameters, I can execute this on my laptop (character differ due to  cp1250 encoded terminal):

```
>>> MySQLdb.__version__
'1.2.3'
>>> sys.version
'2.7.2 (default, Aug 15 2012, 16:03:20) \n[GCC 4.4.3]'

$ mysqldump --no-data -ualko test unicode_test
--
-- Table structure for table `unicode_test`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `unicode_test`;
CREATE TABLE `unicode_test` (
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

$ python test.py
$ mysql -ualko test
mysql> select * from unicode_test;
+--------+------------+
| name   | date       |
+--------+------------+
| ĺĽ ä¸‰   | 2013-11-11 |
| ĺĽ ä¸‰   | 2013-11-11 |
+--------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE**

What are your connection settings?

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> db_conn = MySQLdb.connect(**settings)
>>> cursor = db_conn.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute('select @@COLLATION_CONNECTION, '
...     '@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS, @@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT')
1L
>>> cursor.fetchone()
(u'utf8_general_ci', u'utf8', u'utf8')
```

Comment: the same as you updated above, it's `(u'utf8_general_ci', u'utf8', u'utf8')`